# How can I send an email with bcc receipents in Dynamics Ax2009

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I am sending a batch mail and I want to send a copy (bcc) to an admin mail group. Is it possible to send mail to a bcc receipent in AX 2009?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about AX 2009, but in AX 2012 you can reuse methods `tos()` and `ccs()` and create new ones (`tosBccs()` and `bccs()`) like so:

```
SysMailerAddressField tosBCC()
{
    ;
    return  SysMailerAddressField::create(_com, SysmailerAddressFieldType::Bcc);
}

SysMailerAddressField bccs()
{
    InteropPermission permission = new InteropPermission(InteropKind::ComInterop);

    permission.assert();

    //BP Deviation Documented
    return SysMailerAddressField::create(_com,SysmailerAddressFieldType::Bcc);
}
```

Now, in your email code, where you use `SysMailer` object you can call above functionality:

```
SMTPUserName _bccAddress;
;
if(_bccAddress != "")
{
    mailer.tosBCC().appendAddress(_bccAddress);            
}
```

[Here](http://www.fatihdemirci.net/index.php/2014/09/10/dynamics-axta-bcc-gizli-mail-nasil-gonderilir/) you can find a full example (you may need to use Google Translate though). I'm pretty sure that should work in AX 2009 too.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution. If I use SysMailer  class it has bccs method.
There is a SysMailer example use [here](http://theaxapta.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-send-e-mail-in-microsoft.html).